# uiautomator version is not detected

Tags: android-uiautomator, appium-android

I have uiautomator version 2 is installed in  my PC.
but when the appium severs runs below command

```
adb -s b133582d shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg io.ionic.starter -e disableAndroidWatchers false
```

the it return a warning as below:

This version of UI Automator is deprecated. New tests should be written using
UI Automator 2.0 which is available as part of the Android Testing Support Library.
See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
for more details.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update android sdk tools, check for details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)

Second, reinstall appium:

```
npm uninstall -g appium
npm install -g appium
```

Third, install [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) and run env setup check:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
appium-doctor --android
```

If you get any errors, fix them. Otherwise, start your tests again